# Visual Studio Devexpress item alignment not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

```
Visual Studio Devexpress item alignment not working properly.
I tried to explain in the picture. Thanks for your help.
```

It was working fine a while ago. i don't know what to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J65hr.png

Comment: may be check the dimension of the form window?

Comment: Can you explain a little more

Comment: Sorry, this should be asked at the VSD support website.